# No qualifying bean of type ajuda com esse error:

Tags: java, spring

Estou tentando usar o swing e o spring mas estou com esse problema:

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.market.controller.LoginController' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:346)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1123)
    at com.market.app.MarketApplication.main(MarketApplication.java:17)
    ... 5 more
```

meu main:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import com.market.controller.LoginController;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MarketApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(MarketApplication.class).headless(false).run(args);
        LoginController appLogin = context.getBean(LoginController.class);
    }

}
```

meu controller:

```
package com.market.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import com.market.action.AbstractAction;
import com.market.model.Funcionarios;
import com.market.ui.LoginFrame;



@Controller
public class LoginController extends AbstractController {
    @Autowired
    private LoginFrame frame;



    private void init() {
        this.frame.addWindowListener(this);
        registerAction(frame.getbEnter(), new AbstractAction() {
            private List<Funcionarios> list; 

            @Override
            public void action() {
                if (!frame.getjLogin().getText().trim().isEmpty() || !frame.getjPassword().getText().trim().isEmpty()) {

                }else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, null, "Campo vázio", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void posAction() {
                cleanUp();
            }
        });
    }

    public void show() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void cleanUp() {
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.resetForm();

        super.cleanUp();
    }
}
```

meu view:

```
package com.market.ui;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class LoginFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
    static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 350;
    static final int FRAME_X_ORIGIN = 150;
    static final int FRAME_Y_ORIGIN = 150;
    static final int BUTTON_WIDTH = 90;
    static final int BUTTON_HEIGHT = 30;
    private JTextField jLogin;
    private JTextField jPassword;
    private JButton bEnter;
    private JButton bRegister;
    private JPanel loginForm;
    private JLabel loginText;
    private JLabel passwordText;

    public LoginFrame() {
        setTitle("Login System");
        setSize         (FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        setLocation     (FRAME_X_ORIGIN, FRAME_Y_ORIGIN);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setResizable(false);
        initComponents();
    }
    private void initComponents() {
        loginForm = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
        //buttons
        bRegister = new JButton("Registrar");
        bRegister.setBounds(195, 285, BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
        bEnter = new JButton("Registrar");
        bEnter.setBounds(195, 285, BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
        bEnter.setMnemonic(NativeKeyEvent.VC_ENTER);
        //labels
        loginText = new JLabel();
        loginText.setText("Username:");
        passwordText = new JLabel();
        passwordText.setText("Password:");
        //
        loginForm.add(loginText);
        loginForm.add(jLogin);
        loginForm.add(passwordText);
        loginForm.add(jPassword);
        loginForm.add(bEnter);
        loginForm.add(bRegister);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void resetForm() {
        jLogin.setText("");
        jPassword.setText("");
    }
    public JTextField getjLogin() {
        return jLogin;
    }
    public void setjLogin(JTextField jLogin) {
        this.jLogin = jLogin;
    }
    public JTextField getjPassword() {
        return jPassword;
    }
    public void setjPassword(JTextField jPassword) {
        this.jPassword = jPassword;
    }
    public JButton getbEnter() {
        return bEnter;
    }
    public void setbEnter(JButton bEnter) {
        this.bEnter = bEnter;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está na sua hierarquia de pacotes, por padrão o Spring Boot procura abaixo da hierarquia de onde o método main se encontra:

- Seu main se encontra no pacote `com.market.app`
- Seu controller se encontra no pacote `com.market.controller`

Sugiro você organizar suas classes abaixo de `com.market.app` conforme também indicado na [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html), seu pacote de controller será então `com.market.app.controller`.

Ou você pode indicar seus pacotes utilizando a anotação de `@ComponentScan` indicando o pacote `com.market`, mas como lhe disse, o mais indicado é utilizar a estrutura apresentada na documentação, até por questões de manutenabilidade futuras.

Comment: muito obrigado mano eu tinha refeito e funcionado, mas eu não fazia ideia do motivo, agora funcionou exatamente por conta do meu main está no primeiro pacote.