# Falha ao tentar injetar interfaces Spring Boot

Tags: java, api, rest, spring-boot

Estou desenvolvendo uma api rest utilizando três camadas. Service, Repository e Domain, fiz a injeção do repositorio na service utilizando @Autowired mas quando tento injetar a service na controller da mesma forma é dispara uma exception

```
Description:

Field veiculoService in br.fc.test.controller.VeiculoController required a bean of type 'br.fc.teste.service.IVeiculoService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'br.fc.teste.service.IVeiculoService' in your configuration.
```

Repositorio

```
package br.fc.test.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import br.fc.teste.domain.Veiculo;

@Repository
public interface IVeiculoRepository extends JpaRepository<Veiculo, Long> {

    List<Veiculo> findAll();
}
```

Interface Service

```
package br.fc.teste.service;

import java.util.List;

import br.fc.teste.domain.Veiculo;

public interface IVeiculoService {

    public List<Veiculo> findAll();
}
```

Implementação Service

```
package br.fc.teste.service.implementation;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import br.fc.test.repository.IVeiculoRepository;
import br.fc.teste.domain.Veiculo;
import br.fc.teste.service.IVeiculoService;

@Service
public class VeiculoService implements IVeiculoService {

    @Autowired
    private IVeiculoRepository veiculoRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Veiculo> findAll() {
        return veiculoRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

Controller

```
package br.fc.test.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import br.fc.teste.domain.Veiculo;
import br.fc.teste.service.IVeiculoService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/veiculo")
public class VeiculoController {

    @Autowired
    private IVeiculoService veiculoService;

    @GetMapping
    public  List<Veiculo>  GetAll() {
        return veiculoService.findAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tem mais classes na tua aplicação? Outra implementação para o service de veículos?
Criei um projeto com as mesmas classes que tu postastes aqui e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Talvez relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/401093/no-qualifying-bean-of-type-ajuda-com-esse-error/401364#401364

Answer (score 0):

Inclua a anotação @Component na sua interface, desta forma:

```
package br.fc.teste.service;

import java.util.List;

import br.fc.teste.domain.Veiculo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public interface IVeiculoService {

    public List<Veiculo> findAll();
}
```